# Unable to run small php program in WAMP PHP

Tags: php, wamp

I have installed 64-Bit WAMP Server on my local computer. I have a sample php program placed under `c:/Users/Admin/Documents/First.php`. I have checked the phpmyadmin.conf and it looks as below:

```
Alias /phpmyadmin "c:/wamp64/apps/phpmyadmin4.6.4/"
<Directory "c:/wamp64/apps/phpmyadmin4.6.4/">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride all
  <ifDefine APACHE24>
    Require all granted
  </ifDefine>
  <ifDefine !APACHE24>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
    Allow from localhost ::1 127.0.0.1
  </ifDefine>
  # To import big file you can increase values
  php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 128M
  php_admin_value post_max_size 128M
  php_admin_value max_execution_time 360
  php_admin_value max_input_time 360
</Directory>
```

I have made sure the WAMP server is running and all services are good.

When I try to run the following on IE: `http://localhost/c:/Users/Admin/Documents/First.php`

I get the following error:

You don't have permission to access `/c:/Users/Admin/Documents/First.php` on this server.

Can someone guide me through the steps, to run my program successfully?

Comment: You can not execute files like this. You have to put that file in to wamp folder to execute php files

Comment: @PankajMakwana Even so, it shouldn't give this error. It would just display as plaintext, not give a permission error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WAMP should have created its own folders. If you have installed WAMP on `C:` the folder to place your script in, should be s.th. like `C:\WAMP\www`. Place your script `First.php` in that directory and then call `http://localhost/First.php` via browser. That should run...

Comment: Hi, This has worked for me. The program now executes. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

your php file should be inside the xampp->htdocs->yourfile.. you cannot simply put the php file at any directory. wamp->htdocs for wampserve if im not mistaken

Answer (score 1):

If you want to open your script in the browser you want to put the file inside the web root of your WAMP.

If this is a script which does not require web interface you can always use CLI and run the file using the CLI.